# CORS error in firebase python cloud function

Tags: python, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

My firebase python HTTP cloud function keeps throwing the CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://<project>.cloudfunctions.net/<fn_name>' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

even though I'm handling the preflight requests:

```py
def get_user_db_exist(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """

    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
    print(request)
    return (json.dumps({ 'status': 'sucess' }), 200, headers)
```

I tried setting `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` to `'GET'`, `'POST'`, `'GET, POST'` to no avail (The request from frontend is a POST Request).

I also tried creating a copy of an existing function that worked. While the existing function worked, the newly created duplicate threw the CORS error.

[google cloud function python CORS error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035357/google-cloud-function-python-cors-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/55371251) and instructions at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors-python didn't work.

The frontend is a React app which uses firebase sdk version `7.14.3`. (It didn't work with `v7.14.2` either).

Comment: Are you sure your code for OPTIONS is being used at all? Can you add some debugging to the options request or set a custom header for you to check if you get it in React? No experience with Flask but found this note: *Starting with Flask 0.6, OPTIONS is implicitly added and handled by the standard request handling*

Comment: Maybe it will help if you post the route config for you Flask app.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the OPTIONS method used in the preflight request (to see which options are allowed by the HTTP resource)?

I'm not using a flask app either, frontend is React, with firebase as the database, so used the python cloud function

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set response headers correctly. Change

```py
return json.dumps({ 'status': 'sucess' }, 200, headers)
```

To:

```py
return (json.dumps({'status': 'sucess'}), 200, headers)
```

The complete code:

```py
from flask import json


def cors_enabled_function(request):
    # Set CORS headers for preflight requests
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for main requests
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }

    return (json.dumps({'status': 'sucess'}), 200, headers)
```

And this is the frontend app running on `http://localhost:5000`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your front end app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onload = async function () {
        const endpoint = 'https://us-central1-xxxxx-218808.cloudfunctions.net/cors_enabled_function';
        const res = await fetch(endpoint, { method: 'POST' }).then((res) => res.json());

        console.log('res:', res);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output of the `console.log`: `res: {status: "sucess"}`

Check the response header from browser:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 40
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 13 May 2020 09:05:21 GMT
function-execution-id: maluigz9ytxx
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
x-cloud-trace-context: 853d11ceef85ec4a231d45dd59f7377e;o=1
```

`access-control-allow-origin: *` header set up successfully.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake while copying code into the editor. The cloud function that I deployed had the correct syntax. The cause of the issue was apparently a permission error that didn't allow unauthorized access.